# Bitmap size exceeds 32bits when create bitmap onSizeChanged

Tags: android, bitmap

My custom view works well on most device, but I got some crash report as this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
bitmap size exceeds 32bits
android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:903)
android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:880)
android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:847)
org.islq.board.BoardView.void onSizeChanged(int,int,int,int)(Unknown Source)
android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:15770)
......
```

my custom view has the following piece of code:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if (this.background != null) {
        this.background = null;
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }

    this.background = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);// throw exception at here

    Canvas localCanvas = new Canvas(this.background);
    drawBackgroundGrid(localCanvas);
}
```

This exception is only thrown on "Android 4.4.2,level 19" devices.
how to fix it?

Comment: What values are w & h?

Comment: Your values w,h are 0 or less then 32 wenn multiplicated somehow ... Check this...

Comment: what do you need this.background for?

Comment: @Piperoman:  w,h comes with onSizeChanged(int w, int h ...), it's a custom view, called by android framework.

Comment: @pskink: draw a background bmp and reuse it later

Comment: @param w Current width of this view : it's should not exceeds 32bits?